# How do I add a computed property to a collection?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm using Knockout and binding an observable collection to markup.

It would be great if I could add a computed function to each item in the collection, but I'm not sure of how to properly do this in Knockout.

For example, given this model:

```
var model = {
    'persons' : [
        { firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith" },
        { firstName: "Sgt.", lastName: "Shiney-Sides" },
        { firstName: "Rusty", lastName: "Schacklefurt" }
    ]
};

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

I'd like to add a `fullName` computed function that concatenates the first and last names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jonathanconway's answer is correct but a bit backward and its heavy on memory usage for big collections, move the declaration of the class out from the create method.

Then just call the constructor from the create function like

```
create: function (options) {
   return new Person(options);
}
```

To save even more memory you can move the computed to the prototype declaration.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using the [Knockout Mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).

The code would look something like this:

```
var model = {
    'persons' : [
        { firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith" },
        { firstName: "Sgt.", lastName: "Shiney-Sides" },
        { firstName: "Rusty", lastName: "Schacklefurt" }
    ]
};

// specifies the create callback for the 'persons' property
var mappingOptions = {
    'persons': {
        // overriding the default creation / initialization code
        create: function (options) {
            var Person = function () {
                this.fullName = ko.computed(function () {
                    return this.firstName() + ' ' + this.lastName();
                }, this);

                // let the ko mapping plugin continue to map out this object, so the rest of it will be observable
                ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, {}, this);
            };
            return new Person();
        }
    }
};

model = ko.mapping.fromJS(model, mappingOptions);

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

Credit to [Allen Rice](http://www.underwatergorilladome.com/author/allen-rice/) for [this solution](http://www.underwatergorilladome.com/how-to-use-knockouts-computed-observables-with-the-mapping-plugin/).